Google Rankings Dropped After URL Changes and 301 Redirects – Page Validation Failing
We recently implemented significant changes to the URL structure of our website. To mitigate any negative impact, we set up 301 redirects from the old URLs to the new ones. These redirects have been thoroughly tested using multiple tools (e.g. Developer Tools and redirect checkers like wheregoes), all of which confirm they have been correctly implemented.
Our Google rankings have dropped significantly. Additionally, Google Search Console reports that the pages are failing validation, even though the redirects function as expected.
To resolve this, we took the following steps:

Verified all 301 redirects are correctly pointing to the new URLs.
Submitted a new sitemap containing both the new URLs and the old redirected URLs to encourage reindexing.
Checked for server response issues or crawl errors (none found).
Monitored Googlebot's behavior to ensure it's crawling the redirected URLs.

Despite these efforts, the rankings continue to drop, and the validation errors persist. We suspect there might be something we are overlooking.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with a large-scale URL change and redirect setup? What additional steps or best practices would you recommend to resolve this issue so we can regain control?
Key details:
•   The website runs on BigCommerce.
•   Old and new URLs are properly listed in the submitted sitemaps.
•   Page content remains unchanged; only the URL paths were updated.
•   Redirects were implemented several weeks ago.
Thank you for any insights or guidance

Sorry to hear that, for what I read you follow all the steps correctly. And everything seems pretty much implemented. However, I will check the robots.txt file. If you have a CDN, I highly recommend to deactivate this until you complete the full migration.
Download the free version of Screaming Frog Spider (500 urls for Free) to check if there is any 500 Internal Server Error. There are times where the server is causing this issue.
Another thing to check, is if the temporary domain was not indexed on Google. There is times developers forget to not index the temporary domain.
Type on google: "site:yourtemporarydomain.com"  and see if it's not indexed. If yes, you found the error.
I hope this help!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
